# OOTB edit webpart not working with IE11

Tags: 2010, custom-actions, out-of-the-box

The clicking on edit webpart OOTB arrow was working as expected . When i set the compatibility mode to IE 10,9,8 works as expected . But the arrow doesnt work in IE 11 . How do i fix it permanantely ? Can i set compatibility option in master page ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few ways to address this:

- In IE11 update the sites that open in compatibility mode.
- You can deploy via Group Policy sites that are required to run in compatibility mode so you don't have to set this per user.
- `Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Compatibility View`
- You can add this to your master page

  - `meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10"`
- Apply this hotfix to SharePoint servers

  - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088